# Laravel 9 access .env var in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a new .env variable:

```
ALLOW_REGISTER=false
```

I try to access it in blade like this:

```
    <script>
        let ALLOW_REGISTER = "{{ config('app.allow_register') }}";
        let ALLOW_REGISTER = "{{ env('ALLOW_REGISTER') }}";
    </script>
```

It is empty. I tried adding the var into config/app.php:

```
'allow_register' => env('ALLOW_REGISTER'),
```

After that I did clear all cache. I did run npm run dev and restarted everything. Still empty.

The weird thing is that other .env vars do work, e.g.:

```
let ALLOW_REGISTER = "{{ env('APP_ENV') }}";
```

Whats going on here? How can I access the value of ALLOW_REGISTER? Why other .env vars work?

Comment: "it is empty" you mean an empty string is what you get? ... what values do you get when you convert booleans to strings?

Comment: I'd recommend `let ALLOW_REGISTER = @json(config('app.allow_register'));` which will print `true` or `false` while also ensuring any non-boolean values are safely escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not casting to `string` a `bool`ean, so PHP literally does not append any string.

You can check this behaviour by just doing `echo true` and `echo false`, you will see nothing is output (try it out in the terminal `php -r 'htmlspecialchars(true);'` and `php -r 'htmlspecialchars(false);'`, you can see no string is returned back. [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is what it is being used when you do `{{ something }}`).

So, follow this steps: first you need to add a config, you did end up having `'allow_register' => env('ALLOW_REGISTER'),` inside `config/app.php`, and that is correct (you can put it in any `config/*.php` file that is relevant for you.

Then, you need to use `config('xxxx.allow_register')`. Following your example (using `config/app.php`) it is going to be `config('app.allow_register')`.

Then, if you are using `php artisan config:cache` in your production server (you should be using it), remember to run it again. If you are using that command locally, please don't do so, it is going to mess up your tests and more stuff that when developing is just a pain... (in that case run `php artisan config:clear` and never run it again locally).

Last step is, you should be using `{{ (string) config('app.allow_register') }}` in your blade view (I would suggest to pass it from the controller, instead of requesting the value on the view, but following your case, your issue is that you literally asked for the value.

What do I mean? if `config('app.allow_register')` returns `true` or `false`, it will literally do `{{ true }}` (or `{{ false }}`), and the `{{ }}` laravel helper (PHP code) will literally execute `true` (or `false`), hence doing nothing...

What you want to do is escape the value, so it can be inserted as text, so javascript can interpret it. Your solution is: `{{ (string) config('app.allow_register') }}`.

You need to cast it to string, and PHP does not automatically casts `true` and `false` to strings, so they are literally not displayed or writen in HTML.

---

One quick tip: NEVER use `env` outside a `config` file, because you should be using `config:cache` so the config is load faster. When you use that command, it will automatically return `null` for any `env(...)`, so it will break your code, more info about this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-env).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but it only works like this:

```
    <script>
        @if (env('ALLOW_REGISTER'))
            let ALLOW_REGISTER = true;
        @else
            let ALLOW_REGISTER = false;
        @endif
    </script>
```

Also run `php artisan optimize:clear` if you have laravel 7+

Maybe someone can explain why it works only like this and is not accessible directly

Answer (score -1):

Better way to pass these kind of data - is from Controller which returns that view just like this:

```
public function index(): View
{
    return view('some.view', 
        [
           'isRegisterAllowed' => config('app.allow_register')
        ]
    );
}
```

And in your view like this:

```
<script>
        let ALLOW_REGISTER = !!{{ $isRegisterAllowed }}
</script>
```

Note: never use **env** function in your code - it`s unsafe!

Comment: its not that it is "unsafe"; that isn't the issue ... the issue is that if you cache your configuration it no longer reads the env which is why you are supposed to use the config system directly instead of directly accessing env

Comment: unsafe not because of cyber security issues, but for prod/stage usage, for sure i meant that it could be cached and then semantics will be corrupted after any changes :)